# I use Sublime for my HTML and CSS, but now I need to use JS, what do I do?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I'm new to web development and I started using Atom but I found though it was  really awesome, it was slow and lagged, while Sublime Text is very very fast. I have been building a site on Sublime and now need to use JS for some stuff. But apparently Sublime doesn't support JS? So can I use Atom or another Text Editor to create my JS files then put it into my website folder as well or is there a way to use JS in Sublime. Thank you

Comment: Interesting I thought Sublime came pre-packaged with Javascript set Syntax. In your Sublime text editor. Press CTRL+SHIFT+P and the navigate to `Package Control:Install Package` and then search for `JavaScript Set Syntax` hit enter. restart sublime and you'll have JavaScript color highlighting enabled.

Comment: The solutions provided by others are correct. Just in case you get into a similar situation in the future, you can always combine different editors for your files, it doesn't really matter as long as it are good editors. A good alternative to Sublime Text is Visual Studio Code, but Sublime Text is awesome as well, both editors work well for most languages with the correct plugins installed.

Answer (score 0):

To execute javascript you can add a build system to sublime. Go to  `Tools > Build System > New Build System`. Add this `{
  "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/node", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.js"
}` Save it as a JavaScript.sublime-build  in Sublime Text > User. Then you can easily debug your .js files from Sublime.

Comment: So I save it in the User folder and call it Javascript.sublime-build, but they give me a bunch of options for "save as type" what do I select do i just type ".sublime-build" and select  all files as the type? Sorry I'm new to this kind of stuff.

Comment: @BrownBoii333 yes .sublime-build is the extension.

Comment: @BrownBoii333 here is a small article to walk you through it https://pawelgrzybek.com/javascript-console-in-sublime-text/